# log-odds score from PAM matrix

Tags: bioinformatics

I wrote a small prototype for coding PAM matrices. The PAM matrices I generate are OK compared with other sources. However, I have troubles when deriving the score matrix, `S`, out of the `PAM` matrix. Indeed, depending on the order (`PAM10`, `PAM250`) I have to select different logarithmic bases to make my score matrix suit with reference ones. For example:

- for PAM10:  S10 = 2*log2(PAM10/f)
- for PAM250: S250 = 10.0*log10(PAM250/f)

where `f` are the aa frequencies. I feel quite puzzled with such formula inconsistency. I can not find anything about this in the Dayoff seminal paper. Could you tell me what is going on ? Thx

Comment: You'd probably better ask this at BioStars.  This seems more like a science question than a problem with code.

That said, in general, an expression like `N*logN` makes me think of an alphabet of `N` characters.

Comment: thx for the hint